# HTML5 Canvas "The Bleeding-effect" with text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-canvas

I have my canvas hidden on page load:-

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="915" height="900" style="visibility :hidden; border : 2px double #000000;"></canvas>
```

**`Question 1:)`**
I want to make it visible on button click:- //Submit button//

```
<asp:Button ID="Button6" BackColor="Silver" OnClientClick="store_memID(); document.getElementbyID('myCanvas').visibility = 'visible'; return false;" Style="margin-left: 20px" runat = "server" Text="Submit" Width="102px" Font-Bold="True" Height="28px" />
```

Something like that, although that doesn't work. Incorrect syntax is my assumption...any ideas?

**`(Question 2:)`**
Also when I re-draw on the canvas, everything comes out good, but when the text-stuff is reprinted, it becomes a little 'muddy'.. distorted. I m thinking to solve this the easiest way to do it would be to erase the canvas completely and redraw it. Suggestions as to why 'the muddy effect' and solutions for it?

**`(Answer 2:)`** The bleeding effect was resolved by adding `canvas.width = canvas.width` at the begining of my canvas script.

However, the `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 915, 900);` didn't resolve the bleeding effect.

Comment: I'm guessing your comment is right: if you're redrawing the same shape over and over, you will need to clear the canvas before each re-draw to prevent the shape from 'bleeding'

Comment: Clear with either: `context.clearRect ( x , y , w , h );` or `canvas.width = canvas.width;`

Comment: what is x and y ?assuming w=width and h= height of canvas

Comment: If you're clearing the entire canvas, then x and y are both zero.

Comment: yeah i figured it would be 0's since the entire canvas needs to be gone and I tried that, but it didn't do away with the 'bleeding effect'

Comment: In addition, what is the correct syntax for hiding and making visible the canvas ? for example hiding on page load is set in javascript in the canvas tag, how abt making it visible on click on submit button. i tried to implement the functionality that i have documented here but i know that is not the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1:

Further to my comments, `clearRect` should work assuming your code is correct. It's more preferable to the `canvas.width = canvas.width;` method as it's a fair bit quicker. I suspect it's not working due to the 2nd point below.

---

#### Question 2:

A couple of things:

1. You're missing a quote (") at the beginning of your style property in your jsFiddle.

   ```
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="915" height="900" style = border: 2px double #000000;"></canvas>
   ```
2. You're referencing the canvas "myCanvas" but you're also creating a new one called canvas (referencing the same var).

   ```
    var can = document.createElement("canvas")
   ```

Hiding "myCanvas" will not hide "canvas" (assuming your code is correct - I'm not too familiar with asp).

Comment: Yeah I have 2 seperate layers of canvas-ing. hence the 2 separate references, one is `myCanvas` another is just `canvas`... to allow for a seamless scrolling effect.